# In Provider method throws an error NoSuchMethod:The getter ' ' was called on null

Tags: json, flutter, dart, null, provider

I'm trying to call a variable **placeName** ,but only returns with null.
NoSuchMethod error: The getter'placeName' was called on null. Receiver : null
Tried calling : placeName
As if it could not read the current location from the url!

in my MainPage

```
  GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () async {

                            var response = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder:(BuildContext context) => SearchPage()
                            ));

                            if(response == 'getDirection'){
                              showDetailSheet();
                            }

                          },
```

in my SearchPage

```
void searchPlace(String placeName) async {
    if(placeName.length > 1 ){

      String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$placeName&key=$mapKey&sessiontoken=1234567890&components=country:hu';
      var response = await RequestHelper.getRequest(url);

      if(response == 'failed') {
        return;
      }

      if(response['status'] == 'OK'){
        var predictionsJson = response['predictions'];
        var thisList = (predictionsJson as List).map((e) => Prediction.fromJson(e)).toList();

        setState(() {
        destinationPredictionList = thisList;
        });
      }


      print(response);

    }
  }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


      String address = Provider.of<AppData>(context).pickupAddress.placeName ?? '';
      pickupController.text = address;


    return Scaffold(....)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your appData class was never initialized or never initialized properly. Show your AppData class.

Comment: Show your AppData class. And have you initialize provider class before use? Like `Provider(
  create: (_) => MyModel(),
  child: ...
)`

Comment: To be sure. Do this `Provider.of<AppData>(context).pickupAddress!.placeName ?? '';` Add `!` after pickupAddress

Comment: class AppData extends ChangeNotifier{

  Address pickupAddress;
  Address destinationAddress;

  void updatePickupAddress(Address pickup){
    pickupAddress = pickup;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void updateDestinationAddress(Address destination){
    destinationAddress = destination;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

Comment: After pickupAddress i wrote a ? there ...and it's works finally,but i can already open the Searchpage ,location is null..there is no data, even though API works well.